# Vertically center and top align flexbox elements

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I have a flex container with two items and I would like one item to be aligned at the top of the container, and the other to be in the middle.

How can I achieve this?

I am trying the self-align property in the items, but it does not work.

Comment: Flexbox can't do this natively.

Comment: I am not sure is 100% duplicate. That question is for horizontal alignment and part of the solutions are valid only for the horizontal case

Comment: The issue is the same, one you use row the other column. I added a second duplicate though.